# Adding Totals at the Bottom of Column Group in a Table

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

I am preparing a report which has a Table in it with two ColumnGroups (dynamically generated). The StandardRelays Group is parent group and RelayConfigs group is a child of it. I wan't to print totals for each group at the bottom of respective column. Here is the Report in Design View
[image]

I am able to print the Totals for the child group (RelayConfigs) as well as parent group (StandardRelays) each on a separate row, but the issue is that the parent group total repeats as many times as there are child columns. The output view of the report can best explain what I mean.

[image]

As can be seen, the total marked in red is the total for the parent group (Bombardier Relay in this case) is repeating with the child column. What I would have liked is that the three columns merge at Total Row and output just one total (4 in this case highlighted). Is it possible to achieve this or do I have to change the layout to print column group totals as separate column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on cells that stretch across columns to have all of them highlighted.  Right Click.  Merge Cells.  Expression is now shared in scope of cells above it.

EDIT:

Okay you are in essence wishing to show a parent expression below it appears in a matrix.  I am not certain if you can do this as a matrix on the detail level is going to be the lowest leaf of a tree structure. You can get totals as you are doing but at the lowest level the matrix is on a detail level expanding out to it's fullest.  However you can quite easily populate the total by customer above it as the parent will only aggregate that which is in common with what you tell it to group on and no more.  Here are two possibilities.

On your 'name' or similar column right click and choose 'Insert Rows'>(Expand to)>'Inside Group Below' then put your expression in for 'Sum(Amount)' or similar.  You now with have a totals showing of the grouping of the names before the details level.

You can also expand and collapse the details level at will with a trick that will show the grouping name UNTIL you hit the '+' sign to expand it.  Right click your 'date' field in the 'Column Groups' of the designer.  Choose 'Visibility' on the left pane.  Choose 'Hide' for 'When the Report is Initially run'.  Check 'Display can be toggled by this report item' and choose your parent group of whatever the 'name' of products is.

Mimicking your data I did this:
[image: Example Picture of Test Data]

Comment: The Merge Option Gets disabled when I click on the Cell.

Comment: My bad, I forgot we were dealing with a matrix report and not a tabular.  Add a group that is the parent column group of the 'Sub Total' if this is a matrix.  This would then take the aggregate of all and make a summary column due to it's scope of being the parent would be my guess.

Comment: Doesn't work. I can't get the total columns for the topmost (parent) group to merge. Meanwhile, I have used the conventional Total for matrix where the total appears after the respective column group. The question is still open though, as I would like to how this can be achieved.

Comment: I am not certain if you can get parent rows below the details successfully in a matrix like you want.  See my updates for more possibilities.  The problem is you are trying to add a summary row below a details row in an object that is expanding dynamically.  Even if you get the totals there, which you have done, you are going to get it to create n columns where n is the details being added.  You can circumvent this by going above it instead of below.

Comment: Oh I see, this idea never occurred to me. I am very happy with the approach outlined by you. It won't make much difference as to whether the Parent total appears just below the Parent or at the bottom of the Matrix. I will take your approach and modify my report accordingly. Thanks for all the help